# SonarQube +Unit Test coverage +Java Project

Tags: java, linux, windows, jenkins, sonarqube

I am invoking SonarQube analysis from Jenkins and able to get the Unit Test Success Percentage but not able to see the Unit Tests coverage???
Can anyone please help in getting this in Sonar dashboard?What parameter should I add while invoking from Jenkins?Please let know for both Windows and Linux machines?

This is a huge blocker for my project.Please help.Sonar version is 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

With maven you can build your project using the Jacoco plugin and then you can configure Sonar to use the Jacoco report. I don't think there should be a difference between Linux and Windows, except on loading the Sonar web server.

More information is @ http://www.sonarqube.org/measure-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar-updated/

Comment: Hi Rami, Thank You.I dont know how to generate Jacoco.exe which will be passed as a parameter in invoking sonar analyis from Jenkins.But this will be an exe file.How come it work in Linux machines?
I see few of these parameters while calling sonar from jenkins-
sonar.jacoco.reportpath=target/jacoco.exec
I dont know how to do this in windows and Linux.exe file in linux how it will work ?

Comment: FYI,..I have generated the xml files containing testsuite results and this xml file is used to generate unit test percentage in sonar.But the coverage is not coming?how to do this?

Comment: try using this command when building your Project.  mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

Comment: I am not using maven.this is a java project and I am using Ant to build the project.Please can you brief me what I need to get the unit test coverage in sonarqube dashboard??
Steps completed:
1)Java build to generate the .class files and packed into ear
2)An ant script to execute the cactus test scripts -this will generate the xml files which will be used to generate the unit test result
3)Now in sonarqube,I am able to get the unit test result but not unit test coverage

Comment: I am not aware on how to use Jacoco with Ant. The process is to build your project and use Jacoco to generate the Jacoco report. The latest version of Sonar will be able to read the report without any configuration as Jacoco is integrated with Sonar.

Comment: Ok..How to use jacoco.exec in linux?Because my main task to execute Sonar in linux machine.
.exec will not be supported in linux